# PHP populate using data from table

Tags: php

I'm trying to populate drop down option with the data from table :

```
<?
$sqloption="SELECT name FROM user";
$resultoption=mysql_query($sqloption);

$options="";

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($resultoption))
    {
        $nameoption[]=$row['name'];
        $options.="<OPTION>".$nameoption</option>";
    }
?>


<SELECT>
<OPTION>Choose user<?=$options?>
</SELECT>
```

The button is getting displayed but it has no options. How do I correct this?

Comment: There are so many things wrong with this piece of code, but foremost; please do not use `mysql_*` functions for any piece of code that you value. Lookup `mysqli_* ` or better `PDO`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can populate the dropdown menu using many method:

**mysql_fetch_array()** fetches a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both. It returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or FALSE if there are no more rows. The type of returned array depends on how $result_type is defined.

```
<?php 
     $sql="SELECT name FROM user";
     $result=mysql_query($sql);
?>
<select name="user">
   <?php while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
      <option value="some_value"><?php echo $row['name'];?></option>
   <?php }  ?>
<select>
```

**mysql_fetch_assoc()**  fetches a result row as an associative array. (column names as key)

```
<?php while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>
     <option value="some_value"><?php echo $row['name'];?></option>
 <?php }  ?>
```

**mysql_fetch_object()** fetches the result row as an object.

```
<?php while ($row=mysql_fetch_object($result)){ ?>
    <option value="some_value"><?php echo $row->name;?></option>
<?php }  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you storing them in an another array? Fix the errors. Just do -

**PHP**

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($resultoption))
{
    $options.= "<OPTION>". $row['name'] ."</OPTION>";
}
```

**HTML**

```
<SELECT>
   <OPTION>Choose user</OPTION>
   <?=$options?>
</SELECT>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$sqloption="SELECT name FROM user";
$resultoption=mysql_query($sqloption);

$options="";

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultoption)) {
    $nameoption[]=$row['name'];
    $options.="<OPTION>".$row['name']."</option>";
}
?> 

<SELECT>
<OPTION>Choose user<?=$options?>
</SELECT>
```

You've forgotten a "." after `$nameoption`.
And by the way, you cannot do `$options.="<OPTION>".$nameoption</option>";`
because it's an array. PHP can't print an `array()` directly.

I've kept your `$nameoption` if you need it. Also, I suggest switching from `mysql` to `mysqli` because `mysql_` is deprecated.